# Nifti image into scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nifti

I wanted to use scikit-learn Machine learning variation to do data processing of my neuroimaging data, specifically, fMRI data in Nifti file type.

Nilearn provides the platform. However, I don't understand how the [Nitimasker](http://nilearn.github.io/auto_examples/manipulating_visualizing/plot_mask_computation.html) working principle. How it converts 4D fMRI data to 2D data for scikit-learn.

I have 4D data of 1 subject, i.e `(40, 64, 64, 1452)`, a Haxby data. I use [Nibabel](http://nipy.org/nibabel/index.html) for accessing the images. If I want to process one planar, `[20, :, :, 1]` to `[20, :, :, 1452]`, could I `np.flatten` it to be the `[n_samples,n_features]` for scikit-learn platform?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer but have a look at [nilearn](http://nilearn.github.io/#) which is an extension of scikit-learn for brain imaging data (not sure this is the correct description).

There is an example of the [Haxby data](http://nilearn.github.io/auto_examples/plot_haxby_simple.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-haxby-simple-py)